# How do I change the grid color?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hey guys I am using the following code but want to change the grid color to orange. Currently, it is making a grid over a basketball court image where the grid is black. Defining the grid color with RGB does not work:

Error Code:

line 38, in 
im[:,::dy,:] = grid_color
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (6720,111,4)

How can I achieve this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import pylab as pl

img = Image.open('PATH_TO_IMAGE')

im = pl.imread('PATH_TO_IMAGE')

width, height = img.size


newh = height/2
neww = width/2

print(newh)
print(neww)



dx, dy = int(newh/30), int(neww/55)

print(dx)
print(dy)

#this is not working
#grid_color = (255,165,0)
# im[0,height,dx] = grid_color
# img[:,0:width:dy] = grid_color

#this is where I determine the grid but I dont know the value for orange
im[:,::dy,:] = -1500
im[::dx,:,:] = -1500



# Show the result
plt.imshow(im, extent =[0,110,0,60] )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the shape of `im`, it seems like you have an RGBA image. Try adding the fourth element, *alpha*, to your `grid_color`:

```py
grid_color = (255, 165, 0, 255)
im[:, ::dy, :] = grid_color
im[::dx, :, :] = grid_color
```